# Various Options/Tools for Data Visualization by Oracle

Tags: data-visualization, obiee, datavisualization.toolkit

I was told by some experts that various product offerings are available for visual analyzer from Oracle. For example VA inbuilt with OBIEE, DV inbuilt with OAS and OAC, Oracle Visual Analyzer, BICS Data Visualization etc. I am bit confused with all these names and options and want to know a complete list of Data Visualization tools/options. More over if Oracle Visual Analyzer is a separate tool then how it is different than VA in OBIEE or DV in OAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) BICS is dead since years
2.) VA is the old name of DV. It's not called VA in any current prodcut anyymore. Only in outdated / no longer supported ones.
3.) Data Visualization is a part of OAS (Oracle Analytics Server on-premises), DV is a part of OAC (Oracle Analytics Cloud...in the cloud) and DV is branded as OAD (Oracle Analytics Desktop...for the desktop)

Your "experts" should consider staying up-to-date maybe or not claim "expert" status ;)